# Show that $2k\choose k$ divides the lcm of $1, \dots, 2k+1$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients

I want to show that $(2k+1){2k\choose k}$ is a factor of $\text{lcm}(1, \dots, 2k+1)$.

Clearly the divisor is equal to $2^k\frac{1\cdot3\cdot\dots\cdot (2k+1)}{k!}$, but I don't know how to show that this divides the least common multiple.

Comment: My guess is for each prime $p$ try to proof RHS contains more $p$ in prime factorization.

Answer (score 2):

If $p^m||n$, we will say $v_p(n)=m$.

Here, I will prove $$v_p\left(\binom{2n}{n}\right)\le v_p(\text{lcm}[1,2,3,\dots,2n])$$
Note that for some prime $p$, $$p^m \le 2n < p^{m+1}$$
Then, $$v_p\left(\binom{2n}{n}\right)=\left(\lfloor\frac{2n}{p}\rfloor-2\lfloor\frac{n}{p}\rfloor\right)+\left(\lfloor\frac{2n}{p^2}\rfloor-2\lfloor\frac{n}{p^2}\rfloor\right)+\dots+\left(\lfloor\frac{2n}{p^m}\rfloor-2\lfloor\frac{n}{p^m}\rfloor\right) \le m$$
But note that $v_p(\text{lcm}[1,2,3,\dots,2n])=m$. We are done.

Thus, the RHS contains more primes $p$ in prime factorization, and so we have that $\binom{2n}{n}$ divides $\text{lcm}[1,2,3,\dots,2n]$, or alternatively, that it divides $\text{lcm}[1,2,3,\dots,2n,2n+1]$.